# Надо улучшить код SQL запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Тут такой код запроса SQL:

```
`USE [transport]
GO

SELECT [location].[location] AS Местоположение,[car_list].[status] AS Свободен  
FROM [dbo].[location], [dbo].[car_list]
WHERE [location].[loc_id] = [car_list].[location] AND [car_list].[status] = 1
ORDER BY [location].[location]'
```

Хочу сделать его более расширенным, чтобы мог отображать 3 вида статуса (free, busy, pause) транспортных машин при выборе статуса водителем.

На данный момент у меня получается отобразить только одно значение статуса.

Как расширить код и отображать в одной таблице все статусы как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой запрос выводит данные в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `WHERE [location].[loc_id] = [car_list].[location] AND [car_list].[status] = 1` Вы в запросе выводите данные с статусом = 1, уберите это условие и будет вам радость, будете получать со всеми статусами. А по поводу вывода всех результатов как в таблице - это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Как можно вывести как в таблице?

Comment: Ну для начала, есть статусы: Свободен, Занят, Перерыв. Правильно? Вам нужно делать вывод по статусу: делаете столбец Статус, бьёте на 3 куска, соответственно. И уже в зависимости от локации считаете(как я понял) количество водителей с определенным статусом. Логика такая

Comment: А для более содержательного ответа необходим код того, как водители получают этот статус(а точнее, в какой переменной он хранится). И ещё момент, вы хотите выводить в `phpmyadmin` или на странице, в `php` файле

Comment: оно хранится в сервере и через MS SQL передаёт SQLite на телефон водителя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можно так. Пусть поправят, если решение неоптимально.

```
SELECT location, SUM(free), SUM(busy), SUM(pause)
FROM (
SELECT [location].[location] AS location,
CASE [car_list].[status] WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS free,
CASE [car_list].[status] WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS busy,
CASE [car_list].[status] WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS pause
FROM [dbo].[location], [dbo].[car_list]
WHERE [location].[loc_id] = [car_list].[location]
) AS a
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY location
```

Comment: Попробовал не получилось.  я беру ID из таблицы статуса, через "foreign key" после придаю значение пока что только на таблице а программная часть водителей еще не готова

Comment: @beginneroot, я не осведомлен о точной структуре базы данных, нужным ли образом, например, хранятся статусы таксистов. Так же не уверен в точном синтаксисе Вашей СУБД, алгоритм должен работать. А что выдает сервер?

Comment: Сервер выдаёт ошибку:Сообщение 156, уровень 15, состояние 1, строка 5
Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "FROM".
Сообщение 156, уровень 15, состояние 1, строка 13
Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "GROUP".

Comment: как мне показать структуру базы данных картинку могу на новом вопросе загрузить?

Comment: @beginneroot, я забыл обозначить внутренний запрос. Поправил

Comment: @beginneroot, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc6ef/1 - пример работающей схемы

Comment: Спасибо огромное Akari Gale заработала!!!

Comment: @beginneroot, рад помочь.